# Как позволить пользователю загружать файлы в другую директорию?

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, vsftpd

Я настроил vsftpd, но не могу понять как сделать чтобы пользователь смог загружать файлы в другие директории помимо своей домашней.
То-есть, он может грубо говоря заливать в свою директорию: `/home/username`
а в остальные которые мне требуются не может к примеру: `/var/www/my-domain.com/public_html`

[Настраивал vsftpd по этой инструкции](https://howitmake.ru/blog/debian/63.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно позволять пользователям загружать файлы только на конкретный сайт, то настройку vsftpd лучше всего делать следующим образом:

- делать chroot привязанный к папке /var/www/my-domain.com/public_html
- локально файлы создавать уже как www-data, чтобы не париться с настройкой уже web-сервера.
- создать отдельную директорию с конфигурацией под пользователей.

файл конфига vsftpd будет выглядеть так:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
ftp_username=www-data
chmod_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=www-data
guest_username=www-data
force_dot_files=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=65535
max_clients=10
max_per_ip=10
port_promiscuous=YES
port_enable=YES
listen_port=21
ftp_data_port=20
user_sub_token=$USER
hide_ids=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Так же нужно создать директорию /etc/vsftpd и в нее положить файлы с именем, соответствующим имени пользователя. К примеру содержание файла user1:

local_root=/var/www/www.exmaple.com/htdocs